# Why it's necessary to put setSaveAsActivity false while the targetobjectId is user id

Tags: apex, singleemailmessage

We are trying to send emails to community members from apex. In the current implementation, the setTargetObjectId is contactId. But it's counting towards the daily limit of single email messages. We wanted to use userId to avoid the limit. But it's not allowing to create EmailMessage records if we use userId.

But if we manually try to create an email message record with toIds as userid, it's working always.

Is there any workaround for this issue?

The below code is executing fine, if we try to manually insert the emailMessage and EmailMessage relation record

Note:- Both email to case and Enhanced Email is enabled in our orgs.

```
 List<EmailMessage> emLst = new List<EmailMessage>();       
for(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail : messages) {
        EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();
        emailMessage.status = '3'; // email was sent
        emailMessage.relatedToId = mail.getWhatId();
        emailMessage.fromAddress = ORGWIDE_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        emailMessage.fromName = 'Test User'; // from name
        emailMessage.subject = mail.getSubject();
        emailMessage.htmlBody = mail.getHtmlBody();
        emailMessage.EmailTemplateId = mail.getTemplateId();
            emailmessage.toIds = new String[]{mail.getTargetObjectId()};
        
            emailMessage.ToAddress = String.join(mail.getToAddresses(),',');
        
        emLst.add(emailMessage);
    }
Database.insert(emLst,false);
    List<EmailMessageRelation> emrLst = new List<EmailMessageRelation>();
    for(EmailMessage em : emLst) {
        EmailMessageRelation emr = new EmailMessageRelation();
        emr.EmailMessageId = em.id;
        emr.RelationId = (invMap.get(em.RelatedToId).toId != null)?invMap.get(em.RelatedToId).toId:null;
        emr.RelationType ='ToAddress';
        emrLst.add(emr);
    }
    Database.insert(emrLst,false);
```

Comment: I had checked with salesforce support team and they have given this Idea - https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcAcUAJ/emailmessage-record-for-community-user 
Please vote for this idea if you are also facing issue with emailmessage :)